How to deal with vectors that are orthogonal to cointegration vectors?
In the context of cointegration, when we have the long-term equilibrium defined as $\mathbf{\beta}\mathbf{p} = \eta$, introducing an arbitrary vector $\mathbf{v}$ that is orthogonal to $\beta$ doesn't alter this equilibrium condition as the equilibrium remains expressed as $\beta(\mathbf{p+v})=\eta$. However, if I am using cointegration to do predictions or other similar usages, how should I know whether $\mathbf{p}$ or $\mathbf{p+v}$ is the correct data point as both of them yield $\eta$ after multiplying $\beta$?

What do you mean by correct? If $\mathbf{p}$ are some asset prices, what is the interpretation of $\mathbf{v}$?

@RichardHardy, $\mathbf{v}$ can be arbitrary vectors that are orthogonal to $\beta$; $\mathbf{p+v}$ gives a new asset price.

Hi: if you have a vector that's orthogonal to $\beta$ and you include it during estimation then it will still be part of the estimation process and will change the value of the $\beta$ estimate.  So, I would not use an arbitary orthogonal vector anywhere.

Again, what do you mean by correct? What motivates your question? I could imagine that $\mathbf{p}$ are actual historical prices, so they have a clear interpretation. What would be the interpretation of $\mathbf{v}$?

@RichardHardy, $\mathbf{v}$ can be interpreted as noise, measurement errors, or short-term fluctuations in $\mathbf{p}$. When $\mathbf{v}$ are orthogonal to $\beta$, they will not disturb the long-term equilibrium.

@markleeds, what about if we don't include it in the estimation of $\beta$? We have already found $\beta$ for our model and want to use new data points to test whether our model works well.

Hi Lauchian: If you don't include it in the estimation of $\beta$, then you should not include it in any subsequent analysis either. I'm not sure that I understand your question but noise is generally taken care of at the estimation level through the use of some kind of error term. So, maybe you need to explain more clearly what ${v}$ is.

Lauchian: As I mentioned, I'm not clear the meaning of $\mathbf{v}$ but I just wanted to add that  testing how well cointegration models "work" is not necessarily trivial. It means transforming the  estimaton result into a forecasting model. In the bivariate case of Engle Granger, this  is pretty straightforward because you end up with a univariate ecm.   In the Johansen case, I assume it's a VECM but I have zero experience doing that.

@markleeds, In the Engle-Granger case, you still have at least two dependent variables, so I would say it is still a VECM.

Hi Richard: In  the bivariate case ( EG ), even though the choice is arbitrary,  one chooses which of the 2 variables is on the LHS. So, even though there are two variables, the resulting error correction model is univariate so I would refer to it as an ecm rather than a VECM.  Notice that in the EG case,  there is only one long term relationship, so there is only one univariate ECM.

@markleeds, there are two steps of the EG procedure. What you seem to be referring to is the first step. In the first step, the model is not ECM, it a a model of Y on X in levels. The error correction term (ECT) is obtained as the residual from it. You get a VECM in the second step where you put in the estimated ECT as a regressor. There, both X and Y are dependent variables, so there are two equations, so that is a VECM.

Hi Richard: I'll have to look at Banerjee and Dolado to recall these things. It's been close to 20 years now but,  when I built cointegration models, I always used the error correction model with the $ \Delta y_t$ on the LHS. If there was another one, I never used it. But I believe you. I'll check that out in the text. A really great text if you've never looked at it. Thanks for your comment-correction. If I find anything out different, I'll come back. Otherwise, for people reading this, the EG approach results in two ecm's one of whose existence I either wasn't aware of or forgot about.

Richard: Most of my useful texts are in storage so I've been looking on the internet. So  far, I haven't had any luck looking for a description of the engle granger approach resulting  in two ecm's but I'll keep looking as time permits. So, I'll get back either way but not sure when. Thanks for bringing this up. I'll have learned something either way.

I almost gave up  looking but eventually found proof that the EG method does result in two ecm's. It's odd that the second one is generally not discussed in the literature ? My point is that Richard is correct when he said that, even in the case of EG, the cointegrated system is a VECM. The link below comes from Zivot's SplusFinmetrics  text which I highly recommend for a nice blend of theory and application.  It's old now but probably still as good as it was !!!!!!
https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ584/notes/cointegration.pdf The details of the system are described on page 439.

Oh and not only was Richard correct but I was wrong. I neglected to mention that above. It makes sense when you see it there because you need one ecm to describe the short term changes in $x_t$ and another ecm to describe the short term changes in $y_t$. I still believe that the ecm formulation is easier to deal with in the EG case.
